# How can I stop my React app from re-rendering when I change language?

Tags: reactjs

I have three pages: Home, About, Testimonials. When I navigate to About or Testimonials and change my language from English to Korean (한국어), the page briefly translates the English text to Korean before re-rendering the entire page and returning me to my English home page. I'd like to be able to go to the English About page, click on 한국어 to translate the page from English to Korean and stay on the Korean About page.

How do I stop my page from re-rendering every time I change languages?

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-ix9q2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Seems like it's working well in the codesandbox, no re-rendering the whole page as much as I can see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
        <li className="nav-languages">
          <Link
            className={
              context.state.language === "en" ? "link-active" : "link"
            }
            onClick={context.changeLanguage}
            data-language="en"
            href="/#"
          >
            ENG
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-languages">
          <Link
            className={
              context.state.language === "kr" ? "link-active" : "link"
            }
            onClick={context.changeLanguage}
            data-language="kr"
            href="/#"
          >
            한국어
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

This is in `components/Header.js`. Seemed to work fine after I made this change, that is converted to all anchor tags to `<Link/>`s. Just a workaround don't use it for production, but the correct solution should be somewhere around these lines.

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't use this solution? Is it considered bad practice or are there any bad side-effects?

Comment: I guess there will be warning raised if you use `href` instead of `to` attribute in a `<Link/>` component. So if you're against warnings. This warning is if you're using CRA of course. Plus, I thought that there would be a better solution by just changing the whole semantic markup, <Link/> should not be the go to element here, just a dropdown list with which language the user would like would be nice (personal preference).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

In header.js, replace the anchors(ENG and 한국어) with Link and remove the href props.
anchor has the effect to reload the given href URL and we don't need it.